# Secure JDBC connection from amazon lambda with IAM role as authentication

Tags: aws-lambda

How to establish a secure Aurora DB connection from AWS lambda. How can we set the certificate keystore in AWS lambda functions. Below code snippet shows to establish connection. But the code for setting keystore cannot work with lambda.

```
    private static String generateAuthToken() {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("aws_access_key_id", "aws_secret_key_id");
    RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator generator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
            .credentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).region(regionName).build();
    String authToken = generator.getAuthToken(GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder().hostname(rds_instance_hostname)
            .port(rds_instance_port).userName("iam-database-user").build());
    return authToken;
}
    private static Connection getDBConnectionUsingIam() {
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + rds_instance_endpoint;

    Properties mysqlConnectionProperties = new Properties();
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate", "true");
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("useSSL", "true");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path_to_truststore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustore_password");

    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("user", "iam-database-user");

    // Call a method to generate an authentication token (see above example)
    String authToken = generateAuthToken();

    // Set authentication token as password
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("password", authToken);

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, mysqlConnectionProperties);
}
```

Comment: .... was that supposed to be the headline of a tutorial of some sort? If yes : where is the rest?

Comment: In that case you should rephrase your entire question - because it is written like if it were a tutorial or progress report or something ... thats somewhat confusing. Also do the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: well ... noone will help you without a proper question which contains all of the details - also : noone wants to click on links - this is 2017, even something simple like that can get you a solid virus infection *(if your system is without protection)* You **really** need to to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. updated with code snippet. Here the confusion is on the strategy to set up trust store/ keystore for lambda.